# Add input radio menu to post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, posts, radio

Is there any function to add radio buttons to post and how can I call it? (exampe on img). Thank you for suggestion [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a Custom Meta Box.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

Once you have created and saved the meta field to the post. You can pull it out like regular post meta data.